# Having issue in passing parameter while testing

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, unittesting, test

I'm having an issue while passing parameters to constructor during test. My constructor looks like

```
constructor(address _ethUsdPriceFeedAddress) {
        _owner = payable(msg.sender);
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_ethUsdPriceFeedAddress);
    }
```

My fixture while testing is :

```js
describe("Fund contract", function () {
    async function deployFundFixture() {
        const chainId = network.config.chainId
        const Fund = await ethers.getContractFactory("Fund")
        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        const owner = accounts[0]
        const attacker = accounts[1]
        let _ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = await networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeedAddress"]
        const fund = await Fund.deploy({arguments: [_ethUsdPriceFeedAddress]})
        await fund.deployed()

        return { fund, owner, attacker,_ethUsdPriceFeedAddress } // must return the variables
    }
```

While running **hh test** im getting these error:

```
1) Fund contract
       Deployment
         Should set the right owner:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ethUsdPriceFeedAddress')
      at deployFundFixture (test/test.js:13:67)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at loadFixture (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers/src/loadFixture.ts:59:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:21:37)

  2) Fund contract
       Deployment
         Fund should be more than or equal to 0.01 ethers:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ethUsdPriceFeedAddress')
      at deployFundFixture (test/test.js:13:67)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at loadFixture (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers/src/loadFixture.ts:59:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:25:30)

  3) Fund contract
       Withdrawal
         Only owner can withdraw funds:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ethUsdPriceFeedAddress')
      at deployFundFixture (test/test.js:13:67)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at loadFixture (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers/src/loadFixture.ts:59:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:35:40)

  4) Fund contract
       Event check
         Emitting event correctly:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ethUsdPriceFeedAddress')
      at deployFundFixture (test/test.js:13:67)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at loadFixture (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers/src/loadFixture.ts:59:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:42:30)
```

I am sure i am doing something wrong while passing the parameter to the constructor while testing. Help me to find it, thank you.

Comment: It’s saying networkConfig[chainId] is undefined. You should do console.log to print out the networkConfig and check

Comment: @minhhn2910 rest are okay? i mean my code